# Need a regexp to get all alphabets from # to a non alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regexp to get all the alphabets from # in location.href to a non alphabet.

> Eg1:  Source String 1 : www.example.com#blue?something=x 
> What I
>   expect: blue
>
> Eg2:  Source String 2 : www.example.com#blue&something=x 
> What I
>   expect: blue
>
> Eg3:  Source String 3 : www.example.com#blue 
> What I expect: blue
>
> Eg4:  Source String 4 : www.example.com#?something=x 
> What I expect: ""
>
> Eg5: Source String 5 : www.example.com 
> What I expect: ""

Comment: What do you mean you're looking for one. If you're a programmer, you should be *writing* one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any *sensible* language it'd be as simple as `/(?<=#)[a-z]+/`

Sadly, JS regexes do not support lookbehind assertions, and we are reduced to this:

```
var match = (input.match(/#[a-z]+/) || [""])[0].substr(1);
```

Comment: Maybe [a-zA-Z] to handle upper case as well?

Comment: Just add the `i` modifier like so: `/#[a-z]+/i`

Answer (score 0):

Those URLs are not ... particularly valid (`?` after `#`?), but if they were you could create a Location object from the URLs and use `locationObject.hash` to get the `#`.  As strings:

```
str.match(/#([a-z]+)/i)[1];
```

Comment: "Error: Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference" if the search string has no `#` symbol in it.

Comment: @Kolink yes, I would hope they would be judicious about that

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the URI syntax is:

```
scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

(See [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for further details)

Therefore in your example `#blue?something=x` is the fragment, and there is no query string. Where, if was properly formed:

```
www.example.com?something=x#blue
```

you have `?something` as query, and `#blue` as fragment. To test:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://www.example.com#blue?something=x"

console.log(a.hash, a.search);

a.href = "http://www.example.com?something=x#blue"

console.log(a.hash, a.search);
```

So first fo all you have to check if the URI you have posted are the one you intended, because they seems not well-formed.

Said that, if the examples are correct, you can use something like:

```
function getFragment(s) {
   var v = s.match(/#([^?&]+)/);
   return v ? v[1] : "";
}
```

Or:

```
function getFragment(s) {
    return [].concat(s.match(/#([^?&]+)/))[1] || "";
}
```

But in my opinion is less readable.

P.S.
If you're really interested only in alphabets, you can replace `[^?&]` with `[A-Za-z]`. However, in this way, you won't match URL like  `www.example.com#blue12&something=x` neither `www.example.com#blue_and_green&something=x`. If that the intention, you can replace. Otherwise, keep `[^?&]` will match all the characters that are not `?` or `&`, so it will be more generic.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.. Sometimes the URL is malformed, and I must get the hash from it....